# How many negations do we need to compute monotone functions?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, lower-bounds, matching, monotone

Razborov proved that the monotone function matching is not in [mP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#mp). But can we compute matching using a polynomial size circuit with a few negations? Is there a P/poly circuit with $O(n^\epsilon)$ negations that computes matching? What is the trade-off between the number of negations and the size for matching?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Markov proved that *any* function of $n$ inputs can be computed with only $\lceil \log (n+1)\rceil$ negations. An efficient constructive version was described by Fisher. See also an exposition of the result from the [GLL blog](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2013/12/26/re-gifting-an-old-theorem/).

More precisely:

> **Theorem:** Suppose $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^m$ is computed by a circuit $C$ with $g$ gates, then it is also computed by a circuit $C^*$ with $2g + O(n^2 \log^2 n)$ gates and $\lceil \log (n+1) \rceil$ negations.

The main idea is to add for each wire $w$ in $C$ a parellel wire $w'$ in $C^*$ that always carries the complement of $w$. The base case is for the input wires: Fisher describes how to construct an inversion circuit $I(x) = \overline x$ with $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$ gates and only  $\lceil \log (n+1) \rceil$ negations. For the AND gates of circuit $C$, we can augment $a = b \land c$ with $a' = b' \lor c'$, and likewise for OR gates. NOT gates in $C$ cost nothing, we just swap the roles of $w$ and $w'$ downstream of the NOT gate. In this way, the entire circuit besides the inverter subcircuit is monotone.

> A. A. Markov. On the inversion complexity of a system of functions. *J. ACM*, 5(4):331–334, 1958.
>
> M. J. Fischer. The complexity of negation-limited networks - A brief survey. In
> *Automata Theory and Formal Languages*, 71–82, 1975

Comment: Is it a P/poly circuit?

Comment: Yes, the size of the circuit goes from $g$ to $2g + O(n^2 \log^2 n)$ where $n$ is the number of inputs. I have expanded the response to include a more precise statement of the result, and make it more self-contained.

Comment: And some explicit (multi-output) monotone functions in P/poly [require](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019003004770) at least $\log n-O(\log\log n)$ negations to remain in P/poly.

Comment: It is surprising $\log n$ negations suffice. Thank you.

Comment: For this line of questions (power of negations in circuits/formulae/etc), the following may be relevant: http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2014/144/, https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/902, and  http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2015/026/.

Comment: $2g+O(n\log n)$ is enough by http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/TechnicalReports/abstracts/1995/95-31.html .

Comment: For a minute I thought this was *the* A. A. Markov, but it seems to be published too late.

Answer (score 1):

## How to compute the inversion of $2^n-1$ bits using $n$ negations

Let the bits $x_0, \ldots, x_{2^n-1}$ be sorted in the decreasing order, i.e.
$i<j$ implies $x_i \ge x_j$. This can be achieved by a monotone sorting network like the Ajtai–Komlós–Szemerédi sorting network.

We define the inversion circuit for $2^n-1$ bits $I^n(\vec{x})$ inductively:
For the base case we have $n=1$ and $I^1_0(\vec{x}) := \lnot x_0$.
 Let $m=2^{n-1}$. We reduce $I^n$ (for $2m+1$) bits to one $I^{n-1}$ gate (for $m$ bits) and one negation gate using $\land$ and $\lor$ gates. We use negation to compute $\lnot x_m$. For $i<m$ let $y_i := (x_i \land \lnot x_m) \lor x_{m+i}$. We use $I^{n-1}$ to invert $\vec{y}$. Now we can define $I^n$ as follows:

$$I^n_i := \begin{cases}
I^{n-1}_i(\vec{y}) \land \lnot x_m & i<m \\
\lnot x_m & i=m \\
I^{n-1}_i(\vec{y}) \lor \lnot x_m & i<m \\
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to verify this inverts $\vec{x}$ by considering the possible values of $x_n$ and using the fact that $\vec{x}$ is decreasing.

From Michael J. Fischer, The complexity of negation-limited networks - a brief survey, 1975.